# Unable to install 'Pandas' in python 3.7.4

Tags: python, pycharm, conda

I've installed Anaconda3 interpreter on my PyCharm 3.7.4. I'm not sure that its properly installed.
Now I failed to install pandas. I'm installing it through *File* -> *Settings* -> *Project interpreter* -> *Add packages*.
The error: `TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None`.

Command output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1062, in __call__
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
      exit_code = do_call(args, p)
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
      module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 8, in <module>
      from .install import install
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 19, in <module>
      from ..core.index import calculate_channel_urls, get_index
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
      from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
      from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 3, in <module>
      from libarchive.exception import ArchiveError as _LibarchiveArchiveError
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      from .entry import ArchiveEntry
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in <module>
      from . import ffi
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 48, in <module>
      libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
     return self._dlltype(name)
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
      self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 150, in main
      return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1354, in conda_exception_handler
      return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1065, in __call__
      return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1109, in handle_exception
      return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1120, in handle_unexpected_exception
      self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1190, in print_unexpected_error_report
      from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
      from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
      from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
      from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 7, in <module>
      from .tarball import CondaTarBZ2 as _CondaTarBZ2
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\tarball.py", line 7, in <module>
      import libarchive
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      from .entry import ArchiveEntry
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in <module>
      from . import ffi
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 48, in <module>
      libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
      return self._dlltype(name)
    File "C:\Users\Lena\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

Comment: When you set up your Project Interpreter, did you create a new environment, or add an existing one (i.e., link to your Anaconda **base** environment)?

Comment: Found it!! i just had to set up the interpreter from the "File -> Settings -> Project interpreter -> Add -> System interpreter" instead of "conda interpreter"

Answer (score 1):

Try `conda install python-libarchive-c` (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9055#issuecomment-518729895). Relevant `conda` issues:

- https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9018
- https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9055

Answer (score 0):

Since you have installed anaconda you should have pandas installed try directly importing it.

```
import pandas
```

Comment: It doesn't work: " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' "

Comment: instead of using pycharm why don't you install anaconda from their website and use jupyter notebooks?

Comment: i have multiple files within a project which interact with each other. Is it possible on jupyter?

Comment: everything is just like a normal IDE.

Comment: @KaziAbuJaforJaber that's a bit of an exaggeration. PyCharm has way more out-of-the-box tooling for debugging and profiling. While Jupyter is great for *ad hoc* analysis, it's less than ideal for development.

Comment: since he is trying to use pandas he most likely is trying to do analysis. jupyter is perfect for this kind of job. I don't know why you think he is trying to do development.

Comment: Analysis indeed